# How to implement a short hand link to select date from datepicker for last 7 days or so in html?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a date-picker already implemented in my code. I need to implement a button or link, so that on clicking on it, it can automatically select date for last 7 days or last 1 month or last 1 year (all different buttons) from the datepicker.
Is it possible?

My html code for date-picker :

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="head-label">Date Range:</label>
            <div class="input-group  filter-calendar">
            <my-date-range-picker name="mydaterange" [options]="myDateRangePickerOptions" [(ngModel)]="selectedFilters.date"></my-date-range-picker>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a template reference variable https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars and use in the button

```
<my-date-range-picker #mydate ....>
<button (click)="change(mydate)">click</button>
change(datePicker:any)
{
    datePicker.someMethodToSelect()
}
```

Comment: My question starts from where you left.... So basically what should be implemented in 'date.someMethodToSelect()' so that it return at html components the required date. Suppose I selected 7 days, So my datepicker should select today date as end date and (today-7) as starting date. Can we implement this in 'someMethodToSelect()'.

Comment: I don't know about your "date-range-picker". (is material?, is ng-bootstrap?, is some different?) Today date is new Date(), today-7 is new Date(today.getTime()-7*24*60*60*1000). Tip, you can pass Two